# É comum ter vários servidores diferentes para uma mesma aplicação web?

Tags: banco-de-dados, servidor, hospedagem, aplicação-web

#### Cenário:

Estou começando a participar do desenvolvimento de uma aplicação web. Essa aplicação ainda não está disponível "online", ou seja, só temos ela aqui no servidor de testes onde temos, na mesma máquina, instalado o Redis, SQL Server, IIS, entre outras coisas.

Vamos começar a testar essa aplicação online, ou seja, queremos publicar esta aplicação para que possamos testar a nível de usuário final.

Procuramos algumas hospedagens, etc. E acabei me deparando com o seguinte problema: Não encontrei nenhuma hospedagem que tenha tudo o que preciso. Então, acabei 'distribuindo' a aplicação em três hospedagens diferentes, digo, uso a **hospedagem A** para deixar o meu banco de dados SQL Server, na **hospedagem B** fica o Redis e na **hospedagem C** fica a aplicação ASP.NET que acessa estes bancos de dados.

Como sempre trabalhei com aplicações desktop e o contato web que tive foi de aplicações interna onde tudo (Redis, SQL Server, Aplicação ASP.NET) fica na mesma máquina, isso acaba me parecendo meio estranho.

#### Dúvida:

Essa é uma abordagem comumente usada? Manter cada coisa em um servidor diferente pode me trazer algum tipo de problema?

Comment: Alguns sites tem vários servidores, tanto que a cada período de tempo o **ip** do ping muda. exemplo o Google.

Comment: Sim, mas eu quis dizer especificamente nesse caso. Onde manterei o SQL Server em um, o Redis em outro e a aplicação em outro.

Comment: nesse caso eu acho que perderia performasse, é muito mais rápido o site recolher o conteúdo do próprio servidor do que de outro, e como você quer usar 3 servidores, isso aumentaria 2 solicitações para o usuário poder acessar o conteúdo da página. Na minha opinião isso não é nenhum pouco viável nesse caso.

Comment: Não tem nada de mais. O problema que pode ter é o custo. Se usasse tecnologias que pudessem ser aproveitadas num único ambiente, poderia reduzir o custos drasticamente e simplificar tudo num único servidor. Mas isso tudo também depende do volume de tráfego esperado. Se for um volume alto, é melhor manter da forma como está fazendo, em servidores separados e então vai incrementando com mirrors/load balance, etc. Resumindo, o ponto que deve se preocupar mais é o volume de tráfego. Caso tenha sempre um volume baixo, não compensa toda essa estrutura. Estaria jogando dinheiro no ralo.

Comment: @BrumazziD.B. Nesse caso não tem perda de performance, pelo contrário. É comum ter servidores com "balanceamento de carga" onde apontam para servidores diferentes, replicações, etc. Não aumentaria as requisições, elas serão feitas do mesmo jeito, o que muda é o caminho.

Comment: Uma coisa importante a considerar é que se recomenda pra grandes aplicações ou escalabilidade é ter o DB em MÁQUINA diferente. Só que não pode confundir isso com DB em REDE diferente. Em rede diferente, a perda pode não compensar a suposta melhor performance do DB. Principalmente se a rede for a própria internet. Além disso, quem acessa o DB é o servidor da aplicação, e não o cliente. Então não existe a vantagem do paralelismo que se ouve falar quando se usa uma CDN pra imagens e JS, por exemplo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Irei basear minha premissa em que não existe diferença entre qualidade de serviço entre as hospedagens contratadas. Me refiro a diferença de qualidade entre hospedagens que existe.
> Para essa resposta, irei idealizar que são todas iguais.

Esse caso não é tão diferente quanto você imagina. Pode ser não visível, mas é comum sim. Não entre os três que citou, mas geralmente entre o servidor de banco de dados e o da aplicação.

Mesmo que você contrate um único host, não garante que tudo que irá colocar estará em um único servidor, e é o que geralmente acontece.

Ao configurar o banco de dados, aplicação e o redis você irá apontar o local, que um host te dá os dados de acesso, mas não tem certeza que serão no mesmo servidor. Hosts diferentes são apenas servidores diferentes (isso não levando em consideração a qualidade de cada um).

Existem alguns pontos em relação em separar os serviços em hosts diferentes, que são:

### Segurança

Seu servidor WEB fica disponível para usuários anônimos, levando em consideração que algo não está como deveria, você deixa seu banco de dados e demais informações insegura, por alguma falhar de segurança.

E levamos em consideração que se algum dos hosts for "acessado externamente", você terá um tempo para se prevenir antes de chegar aos demais.

### Performance

Caso seja configurado corretamente, você não terá perda de performance, pelo contrário. Você é obrigado a fazer as requisições, independente se estiver em um host ou não. Grandes empresas como o Google, Facebook e o [StackOverFlow](http://stackexchange.com/performance) utilizam servidores diferenciados, justamente por questões de performance, dentre outras.

É muito comum ver em grandes empresas um host apenas para balanceamento de carga, o que ajuda a manter o serviço online (claro, isso geralmente é implícito, mas acontece).

### Escalabilidade

Uma das maiores dificuldades hoje é escalar o hardware necessário para o sistema funcionar. Separando em hosts, você consegue fazer uma diferenciação melhor de onde está o gargalo e se precisa ou não alterar as configurações de hardware.

### UPTIME

Como o @CiganoMorrisonMendez disse em sua resposta, você consegue manter sua aplicação funcionando mesmo se um algum desses hosts caírem (exceto o da aplicação, logicamente).
Hoje você possui ferramentas para cachear seu sistema e garantir uma funcionalidade quase que independentes, utilizando alguns recursos para salvar os dados caso o host do banco pare de funcionar. Claro, você precisa preparar sua aplicação para isso, mas é possível.

### Custos

Separar seu sistema em hospedagens diferentes, gera custos elevados em seus serviços, o que pode gerar problemas para muitos.

### Complexidade

A dificuldade de se manter três hospedagens é maior do que uma centralizada. Isso irá gerar uma complexidade maior para manter a aplicação em funcionamento.
Uma má configuração desses recursos poderá gerar mau funcionamento da aplicação e/ou perda de performance, como muitos dizem.

**Referências:**

- [Why is it not advisable to have the database and web server on the same machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/659970/4843158)
- [Stackchange Performance](http://stackexchange.com/performance)
- [How to host a single website on multiple servers?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/23437)
- [Autoscale - Facebook](http://www.datacenterdynamics.com.br/focus/archive/2014/08/facebook-cria-sistema-autoscale-para-reduzir-consumo-de-energia)
- [Balanceamento de Carga](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanceamento_de_carga)

Answer (score 9):

> Essa é uma abordagem comumente usada?

Comum não é. É um pouco extravagante, mas não é errada.

> Manter cada coisa em um servidor diferente pode me trazer algum tipo de problema?

Os problemas estão mais relacionados com a complexidade da sua contingência. A escolha de não deixar tudo centralizado pode ou não ser um bônus de performance. Também há a questão da qualidade de cada serviço, a complexidade da administração deles e alguma coisa envolvendo custos. Em resumo, a divisão pode ser tanto uma vantagem quanto uma desvantagem.

Por exemplo, se seu servidor Redis cair, sua aplicação não necessariamente deixará de funcionar, principalmente se o Redis for usado como cache de segundo nível da sua aplicação. Agora, se seu SQL Server cair, mesmo com o Redis funcionando, você derrubará a aplicação mesmo com os outros serviços funcionando. A contingência é muito mais fácil de administrar quando centralizada.

Por outro lado, estabelecer essa divisão cria uma forma interessante de paralelismo. A carga de trabalho fica dividida em três lugares diferentes, que pode ser convertida em ganho de performance.

Answer (score 8):

Estou respondendo baseado no que foi perguntado. Está falando de ter servidores em hospedagens diferentes. As outras respostas dizem coisas que fazem sentido em uma hospedagem com servidores diferentes. Elas estão corretas para o cenário que resolveram responder, não para o cenário da pergunta.

Pra mim a pergunta deixa claro que a separação só está ocorrendo porque não encontraram um lugar que fornecesse tudo junto.

---

Depende do que considera normal. A maioria dos sites são muito simples e precisam de um estrutura bem simples. Por exemplo, é raro o site que precisa de Redis de fato.

É muito raro encontrar alguma hospedagem que oferece SQL Server e não ASP.NET. Muitas oferecem os dois e o Redis (que tenho dúvidas ser necessário).

Esta estrutura até funciona, mas gerará tráfego entre as hospedagens, gerando custos, o que não é o ideal e vai aumentar a bastante a latência de resposta do site. Quanto mais volume de acesso tiver, mais terá dificuldade em lidar com uma estrutura totalmente descentralizada.

Não há como ter melhor performance por ter serviços que são dependentes um do outro em locais físicos diferentes. Isto só gerará maior latência, sem nenhum ganho.

Sem dúvida o fato de ter a carga distribuída **pode** dar melhor performance que ter tudo em um servidor só, mas só se o servidor estiver sobrecarregado, caso contrário só agregará latência sem nenhum ganho. Só medindo para ter certeza quando se deve separar servidores.

Se a opção for ter servidores separados na mesma rede, aí o ganho pode ser mais interessante, mas só nos casos de grande volume de acesso. Se a carga é pequena, adicionar servidores com serviços dependentes entre si, ainda que na mesma rede, certamente adicionará latência, mas pequena e aceitável porque o volume exige isto.

Existe ainda uma possibilidade de se usar *datacenters* diferentes para aumentar o tempo de disponibilidade, afinal um *datacenter* pode sair do ar. Mas se fizer isto, deverá ter cópia total de todos os componentes nos dois *datacenters*. Ou seja, terá um ou mais servidores em cada um deles contendo os 3 serviços relatados: SQL Server, Redis, ASP.NET (provavelmente um IIS).

Mesmo se for pensar em distribuição de carga, isto tem que ser um trabalho de engenharia, não um acidente de percurso.

Possível é, mas não recomendaria fazer, é mais complexo e mais custoso.

Procure um local que atenda todas necessidades. O Azure, só para citar um exemplo, atende.

Você pode pegar uma instância onde pode colocar os 3 serviços juntos ou pode contratar os serviços separados (em geral fica bem mais caro).

Este site, por exemplo, que é um exemplo de site de altíssimo volume que tem seus próprios servidores e organizam sua estrutura de acordo com sua necessidade, eles só usam um segundo *datacenter* como espelho da estrutura regular, não separam cada serviço em uma hospedagem diferente. Eles separam os serviços em servidores diferentes porque este é um dos sites mais acessados do mundo.

A sua necessidade é parecida com a do Stack Overflow? Se não, vá pelo simples. Vá pelo que está acostumado. Só crie complexidade no sistema quando a necessidade surgir.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).