# Servidor para guardar imagens

Tags: php, imagem

Gostaria de saber sobre guardar imagem após o upload.

É seguro guardar imagem no próprio diretório do site ou existe algum servidor para isso?

Por exemplo, tenho um site de notícias e após você cadastrar a notícia, as imagens selecionadas são convertidas e enviadas para o próprio diretório do site, se o site começar a receber muitas notícias, o diretório irá lotar uma hora!

Então tem algum serviço onde mando os arquivos e no diretório do site eu guardo somente arquivos mais simples? Não achei muita coisa na internet sobre esse tema, pode me dar uma ajuda?

Comment: Só é perigoso se você não tratar o tipo do arquivo que foi envidado, permitindo assim que alguém envie um script php e consiga executa-lo externamente.... Quanto ao desempenho, não acho que quantidade de arquivos em um diretório influencie.

Comment: Tem algumas opções de APIs para tratar e armazenar e visualizar imagens como o Cloudinary que já tem uma orientação de como fazer em PHP http://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_integration Esse serviço é gratuito até certo ponto.

Comment: Recomendo ler esta [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11753/por-que-colocar-js-css-e-imagens-em-outro-servidor?noredirect=1&lq=1). Usar outro servidor específico para distribuição de conteúdo como imagens, javascripts tem várias vantagens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> e seguro guardar imagem no próprio diretório do site?

A questão da segurança vai envolver muitas outras coisas, como por exemplo a forma como toda sua aplicação foi desenvolvida, a configuração dos serviços no host, e mais diretamente à pergunta, em como a validação do upload foi feita.

> existe algum servidor para isso?

Sim, pode-se procurar facilmente por API de serviços de hospedagens de imagens que verá até alguns gratuitos para isso.

Outra solução é pensar em distribuir seu conteúdo em outros hosts pensando em questões de performance, por exemplo. Poderia me alongar para falar sobre essa ideia mas nesses dois links abaixo tem boas respotas sobre isso:

- [Por que colocar JS, CSS e imagens em outro servidor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11753/por-que-colocar-js-css-e-imagens-em-outro-servidor)
- [É comum ter vários servidores diferentes para uma mesma aplicação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123430/%C3%89-comum-ter-v%C3%A1rios-servidores-diferentes-para-uma-mesma-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-web/123440)

Comment: perfeito! muito obrigado pela ajuda